# Why does appcmd.exe behave differently when executed inside a batch file?

Tags: windows, scripting, iis-7, batch-file, iis-7.5

I have the following `appcmd` to add an exception to IIS7's ISAPI and CGI restrictions. The exception I am adding should look like:

`c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "%s" %s`

Here is the command line:

```
appcmd set config -section:isapiCgiRestriction "-+[path='c:\perl\bin\perl.exe \"%s\" %s', allowed='true', description='Perl CGI']"
```

If execute this from the command line it does this correctly, however if I execute this inside a `.cmd` batch file the path gets mangled and ends up looking like:

`c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "s`

The trouble seems arise because I have to escape the quotation marks around the first `%s` perl.exe parameter. But why this should behave differently in a batch file is a bit of a puzzle.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Torn between SF and SO for this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the command processor reads your `"%s" %s` and finds two mathing `%` signs, so this makes a valid batch variable (namely `%" %`). And after expanding that into nothing, only your `"s` remains.

You can escape a single `%`-sign in your batch file by doubling it, like this:

```
c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "%%s" %%s
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. That had me scratching my head for ages.